# Use a condition within a loop

Tags: python

A simple substitution cipher may be created by shifting or rotating the alphabet by a certain number of places.  Using this system with a rotation of 5 gives us the following alphabets:

Plaintext alphabet:  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Ciphertext alphabet: FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE

Any plain text message can be translated into the ciphertext by replacing each letter of the plain text alphabet with the letter in the ciphertext alphabet in the equivalent position.  Spaces are left unchanged. For example, using the cipher above, the word DOG is enciphered as OBK. 
Given a String and a rotation value, return the String translated into the ciphertext using the simple substitution method described above. You may assume that the text contains only spaces or capital letters and that the rotation value is always non-negative

function name: rotate_text

arguments:
    text - input text to be encoded
    n - an integer value specifying how many characters to rotate the text by

returns:  a string containing the text rotated as described above

[Testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB8fi.png)

I am able to pass the test, but the result said I am  u therenable to pass hidden or more test, Could someone help me?

```
def rotate_text(string1, int1):
    loL = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K',
           'L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V',
           'W','X','Y','Z']

    strtoList = list(string1)
    list1 = []
    newStr = ""
    if int1 == len(loL):
        int1 = int1 % 26
    for i in range(len(strtoList)):
        if strtoList[i] in loL:
            loLindex = loL.index(strtoList[i]) 
            list1 += [loL[loLindex + int1]]
        elif strtoList[i] == " ":
            list1 += [" "]
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        newStr += list1[i]

    return newStr
```

Comment: If you can access the hidden tests, that would be great. Also, note that for the first `if` statemen, you do `int1 = int1 % 26` if `int1 == 26`. This will always be zero, so you might as well set it to zero instead of `int1 % 26`. Otherwise, great!

Comment: Side note: Instead of `for i in range(len(list1)): newStr += list1[i]`, just do `newStr = ''.join(list1)`. Besides being shorter and faster, it's also the idiomatic way to do this in Python.

Comment: Also: You don't need to do `for i in range(len(list1)):` and then keep doing `list1[i]` inside the loop; just `for ch in list1:` and use `ch` directly.

Comment: And finally: you don't need to turn a string into a list in the first place. A string is an iterable collection of characters, just like the list is. (You could even change `loL` into a string, `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`, or just use `string.ascii_uppercase`, which already is exactly that string.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
list1 += [loL[(loLindex + int1) % len(loL)]]
```

for whenever the cypher "loops back to the first letters".

And then

```
if int1 == len(loL):
    int1 = int1 % 26
```

becomes irrelevant as well.

And BTW, you don't need to build a list and then make it a string. You can grow your string directly too...